# Use Doctrine DBAL Schema Representation in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, migration, schema

I've been using Symfony 4+ to develop a few web applications, I'm developing on MariaDB but would also like the option to deploy to other databases.

When I generate a database migration, it is generated with SQL queries like so:

```
public function up(Schema $schema) {
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE users ...');
}

public function down(Schema $schema) {
    $this->addSql('DROP TABLE users');
}
```

I would prefer to have migrations use the [Schema Representation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-representation.html) and be generated like so:

```
public function createSchema() {
    $schema = new Schema();

    $table = $schema->createTable('users');
    $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', array(
        'autoincrement' => true,
    ));
    $table->setPrimaryKey(array('id'));

        return $schema;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to configure Symfony or the DoctrineMigrationsBundle to generate migrations using the schema representation?

*(Kind of like, but does not have to be an exact match to [Laravel's migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations).)*

Comment: What is the point ? If I understand correctly, the table `users` is already created so there is no need to create it again

Comment: The code above is an example, currently the migrations are generated using `$this->addSql(...);` but I would like to use the object / schema representation as shown in the second example.

Comment: Is this any assistance  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/1.7/reference/generating_migrations.html

Comment: Only a little, I have read that page but can't find anywhere in the Doctrine or Symfony documentation or any results on Google on how to implement that in Symfony to have it generate the DBAL style migrations that use the schema representation.

Comment: When you want to use PostgreSQL later. Change the DB type https://symfony.com/doc/master/cloud/services/postgresql.html and make the migrations again. This will fit to PostgreSQL. Your database structure is in your entitys.